# Strange uncaught_exception_handler in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am getting strange uncaught exception handler in Google chrome. I recently updated all follow buttons to download javascript async. On opening the content.js mentioned in exception I get comment avoid polluting the global JavaScript namespace. Pinterest url is also mentioned. I am not sure if it's due to something I did or pinterest js is not meant for async process and creating error. I see button rendered on site (For further checking pls see http://www.snapchamp.com). Error and js file retrieved on error are below for your perusal. TIA for any directions.

```
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: src.getAttribute is not a function
    at Object.w.(anonymous function).f.canHazButton (eval at <anonymous> (chrome-extension://gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic/content.js:9:17), <anonymous>:481:23)
    at Object.w.(anonymous function).f.init (eval at <anonymous> (chrome-extension://gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic/content.js:9:17), <anonymous>:670:19)
    at Object.eval [as callback] (eval at <anonymous> (chrome-extension://gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic/content.js:9:17), <anonymous>:712:11)
    at a.k (eval at <anonymous> (chrome-extension://gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic/content.js:9:17), <anonymous>:698:23)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (chrome-extension://gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic/content.js:9:17), <anonymous>:717:2)
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic/content.js:9:9)
```

When I opened content.js. I get following:

`

```
// avoid polluting the global JavaScript namespace
(function (c, d) {
  // fail quietly if we can't access the Chrome or document objects we need
  if (c && d && d.body && d.URL) {
    // set a data attribute to body, indicating that the Pinterest extension is installed.
    d.body.setAttribute('data-pinterest-extension-installed', 'cr' + c.runtime.getManifest().version);
    c.storage.local.get('logic', function(obj) {
      try {
        eval(obj.logic);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(obj.logic);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    // if we're pinning, save the timestamp to lastPin
    if (d.URL.match(/^https?:\/\/(.*?)\.pinterest\.com\/pin\/create\/extension\//)) {
      c.storage.local.set({'lastPin': new Date().getTime()});
    }
  }
}(chrome, document));
```

`

Comment: Well I was not able to understand and in absence of any answers, I went back to normal way of including pinterest.js on my site. The error disappeared. Still if some one understand why it happens and provide way to fix it. The error happens when I used dynamic function to include pinterest.js script tags at end of page(I am including facebook, google plus and twitter js file on site that way now). Error is repeatable and wonder why it happens in one case and not in other way of including same js file.

Answer (score 2):

I started having this issue while debugging JS code for client's web app. I thought I noticed something about :extension in the logs - that, and the file is called content.js pointed to JS running in a Chrome extension. I grabbed that hash from your log: gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic, and sure enough, it is same ID for Pinterest chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-it-button/gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic?hl=en

Removed from Chrome, and my site is back to good!